# Convert ActivatedRoute.queryParams to Promise

Tags: angular, promise, observable

I don't want to subscribe to route.queryParams as an Observable but want to make it a Promise to be able to use async/await to do various function calls in ngOnInit.
Unfortunately I fail at this intention. The following implementation gives me no reaction or output:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.toPromise().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: They did something to the mechanism that will prevent you to use that functionality, but I don't know why or what. You probably just have to stick with the subscribe functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I think since `queryParams` is an observable that is long lived, you can't convert it to a promise like so. You need a `take` operator on it to take the first emission and convert that to a promise.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    // add pipe(take(1)) here to take the first emission, close the stream,
    // and convert it to a promise.
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(take(1)).toPromise().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```